# Pandas DataFrame: How to quickly get first non-NaN value in each row?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas
import numpy

list_of_lines = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]

df1 = pandas.DataFrame(list_of_lines)

df1.ix[2, 0] = numpy.NaN
df1.ix[2, 1] = numpy.NaN
```

Is there a way to get the first non-NaN value from each row?

The way I am currently doing it is:

```
df1 = df1.bfill(axis = 1)

my_answer = df1.iloc[:, 1]
```

This gives me:

```
'a'
'a'
'c'
'a'
```

But it is very slow.

Is there some trick or native way of doing this without having to bfill? My dataframe is 1,500 columns x 10,000 rows and it takes a while to bfill.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31828240/first-non-null-value-per-row-from-a-list-of-pandas-columns/31828559#31828559) but that answer is slower than my current method.

Comment: I submitted an answer to the original question which may have the performance you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. I got a 5x speed-up. Exactly what I needed.