# First column name with non null value by row pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want know the first year with incoming revenue for various projects.

Given the following, dataframe:

```
ID  Y1      Y2      Y3
0   NaN     8       4
1   NaN     NaN     1
2   NaN     NaN     NaN
3   5       3       NaN
```

I would like to return the name of the first column with a non-null value by row.

In this case, I would want to return:

```
['Y2','Y3',NaN,'Y1']
```

My goal is to add this as a column to the original dataframe.

The following code mostly works, but is really clunky.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Y1':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5],'Y2':[8, np.nan, np.nan, 3], 'Y3':[4, 1, np.nan, np.nan]})
df['first'] = np.nan

for ID in df.index:
row = df.loc[ID,]
for i in range(0,len(row)):
    if (~pd.isnull(row[i])):
        df.loc[ID,'first'] = row.index[i]
        break
```

returns:

```
   Y1  Y2  Y3  first
0 NaN  8   4   Y2   
1 NaN NaN  1   Y3   
2 NaN NaN NaN  first
3  5   3  NaN  Y1
```

Does anyone know a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can apply `first_valid_index` to each row in the dataframe using a lambda expression with axis=1 to specify rows.

```
>>> df.apply(lambda row: row.first_valid_index(), axis=1)
ID
0      Y2
1      Y3
2    None
3      Y1
dtype: object
```

To apply it to your dataframe:

```
df = df.assign(first = df.apply(lambda row: row.first_valid_index(), axis=1))

>>> df
    Y1  Y2  Y3 first
ID                  
0  NaN   8   4    Y2
1  NaN NaN   1    Y3
2  NaN NaN NaN  None
3    5   3 NaN    Y1
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding `apply` is preferable as its not vectorized. The following is vectorized. It was tested with Pandas 1.1.

#### Setup

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Y1':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5],'Y2':[8, np.nan, np.nan, 3], 'Y3':[4, 1, np.nan, np.nan]})

# df.dropna(how='all', inplace=True)  # Optional but cleaner

# For ranking only:
col_ranks = pd.DataFrame(index=df.columns, data=np.arange(1, 1 + len(df.columns)), columns=['first_notna_rank'], dtype='UInt8') # UInt8 supports max value of 255.
```

#### To find the name of the first non-null column

```
df['first_notna_name'] = df.dropna(how='all').notna().idxmax(axis=1).astype('string')
```

If `df` is guaranteed to have no rows with all nulls, the `.dropna` operation above can optionally be removed.

#### To then find the first non-null value

Using `bfill`:

```
df['first_notna_value'] = df[df.columns.difference(['first_notna_name'])].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
```

Using `melt`:

```
df['first_notna_value'] = df.melt(id_vars='first_notna_name', value_vars=df.columns.difference(['first_notna_name']), ignore_index=False).query('first_notna_name == variable').merge(df[[]], how='right', left_index=True, right_index=True).loc[df.index, 'value']
```

If `df` is guaranteed to have no rows with all nulls, the `.merge` operation above can optionally be removed.

#### To rank the name

```
df = df.merge(col_ranks, how='left', left_on='first_notna_name', right_index=True)
```

Is there a better way?

#### Output

```
    Y1   Y2   Y3 first_notna_name  first_notna_value  first_notna_rank
0  NaN  8.0  4.0               Y2                8.0                 2
1  NaN  NaN  1.0               Y3                1.0                 3
2  NaN  NaN  NaN             <NA>                NaN              <NA>
3  5.0  3.0  NaN               Y1                5.0                 1
```

---

Partial credit: answers by [me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65722008), [piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51972798/), and [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37938780/)

Answer (score -1):

Apply this code to a dataframe with only one row to return the first column in the row that contains a null value.

`row.columns[~(row.loc[:].isna()).all()][-1]`

Comment: That's not what this question is asking for.