# Multiply dataframe columns based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe.

df

```
ID   Q_code    A_value   B_value   C_code  Score 
1    A_code     1         0         1        0.5
2    B_code     0         0         0        1
3    C_code     0         1         1        0
4    B_code     1         1         1        1
```

Based on `ID` and `Q_code`,  for example under Q_code column for `A_code` and `ID == 1` I would like to multiply, `A_value X Score`  and update `Score` value. under Q_code column for `B_code` and `ID == 2`, I would like to multiply, `B_value X Score`  and update `Score` value on that particular row. The same works for others.

```
ID   Q_code    A_value   B_value   C_code  Score 
1    A_code     1         0         1        0.5
2    B_code     0         0         0        0
3    C_code     0         1         1        0
4    B_code     1         1         1        1
```

I have tried this as follows but I would like to consider `ID and Q_code`

```
df['Score'] = df['A_value'] * df['Score']
```

Can any one help with this?

Comment: Is there a finite number of Q_code values? ALso, does ID value alter the final result in any way?

Comment: Yes. There are around 10 Q_code values. Yes, for different ID there might be the same Q_codes.

Comment: The logic is unclear, seems to me that you make Score 0 if all Q_scores are 0 and leave it unchanged otherwise

Comment: Not sure how ID is relevant? doesn't seem to alter the logic or does it?

Comment: You can leave ID and show your possible solution.

Comment: Is your logic only for ID 1 and 2 or there is a general rule?

Comment: @Hiwot can you explicit the logic? If you perform B_value*Score, how is it not 0 for 0*0.5? Please break down the calculation

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to pick values according to Q_code column. In this case you can use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45487394/4819376).

## Data

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {'ID': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4},
 'Q_code': {0: 'A_code', 1: 'B_code', 2: 'C_code', 3: 'B_code'},
 'A_value': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1},
 'B_value': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 1},
 'C_value': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 1},
 'Score': {0: 0.5, 1: 1.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 1.0}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

## Use lookup to select the value from given column

```py
df["new_value"] = df.lookup(
    df.index, 
    df["Q_code"].str.replace("code", "value"))
```

which returns

```sh
   ID  Q_code  A_value  B_value  C_value  Score  new_value
0   1  A_code        1        0        1    0.5          1
1   2  B_code        0        0        0    1.0          0
2   3  C_code        0        1        1    0.0          1
3   4  B_code        1        1        1    1.0          1
```

So now you just need to multiply `df["Score"] * df["new_value"]`