# How to get cell value by column name (different for every row) in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I have a DataFrame with several rows and columns, and for every row, would like to obtain the cell value where its column name corresponds to a certain value, given in the last column, which is different in every row. For example, if my DataFrame is this:

```
d = {'2015': [3, 11, 2], '2016': [14, 5, 6], '2017': [1, 7, 12], 'yr': [2016, 2015, 2017]}
df = pd.DataFrame (data = d, columns = ['2015', '2016', '2017', 'yr'], index = ['d1', 'd2', 'd3'])
```

I want to get as a result:
`output = 14, 11, 12`

I have tried this (for one row) but it does not work:
`output1 = df.loc['d1'][df.columns == df.loc['d1', 'yr']]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using [this replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45487394/3275464) for the deprecated lookup:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'2015': [3, 11, 2], '2016': [14, 5, 6], '2017': [1, 7, 12], 'yr': [2016, 2015, 2017]}
df = pd.DataFrame (data = d, columns = ['2015', '2016', '2017', 'yr'], index = ['d1', 'd2', 'd3'])

idx, cols = pd.factorize(df['yr'].astype(str))
df[cols].values[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
```

The intent is to have a map between each year value and the column position (first line), then to use the numpy array lookups when passed a list of rows (range for you) and columns.

Comment: Thanks! It works. Didn't see that this had already been answered..

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:

```py
# ensure "yr" column is string
df["yr"] = df["yr"].astype(str)

# apply function row-wise to obtain the column value in "yr"
df.apply(lambda x: x[x["yr"]], axis=1)
```