# Python Pandas Conditional Only Executes First "If" Statement

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset 'df' like so:

```
a     b     c    e  f  g
1     Nan   Nan  2  3  4
Nan   1     Nan  2  3  4
Nan   Nan   1    2  3  4
```

I want to create a new column 'd' in my dataframe 'df' like so:

```
   a     b     c    d  e  f  g 
   1     Nan   Nan  1  2  3  4
   Nan   1     Nan  1  2  3  4
   Nan   Nan   1    1  2  3  4
```

So basically, 'd' is the amalgamation of columns 'a', 'b', and 'c' for any non-NaN values those three columns have. Between 'a', 'b', and 'c', if one column is non-NaN, the other columns are NaN. I need columns 'e', 'f', and 'g' in my dataset, but they do not have anything to do with constructing column 'd'

I created this function below:

```
def func(df):
    if df['a'] is not None:
        return df['a']
    if df['b'] is not None:
        return df['b']
    if df['c'] is not None:
        return df['c']
```

and then used `concatenated_df['d']=concatenated_df.apply(func, axis=1)` to apply the conditional statements for each row of the dataframe. However, I am only getting the first if statement to successfully execute. The rest returns NaN values to the new column 'd'

I also tried modifying the function to

```
def func(df):
    if df['a'] is not None:
        return df['a']
    elif df['b'] is not None:
        return df['b']
    elif df['c'] is not None:
        return df['c']
```

but it still only executed the first conditional statement

Comment: So you just want the first value that isn't `None` from a b and c?

Comment: I will update the question with an example to make it more clear

Comment: Are you looking for not-None or not-NaN? (They are not the same.)

Comment: @DyZ maybe that is my issue let me try fixing that

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31828240/first-non-null-value-per-row-from-a-list-of-pandas-columns/31828559

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`first_valid_index`**

```
df['d'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[x.first_valid_index()], axis=1)

     a    b    c  d
0    1  NaN  NaN  1
1  NaN    1  NaN  1
2  NaN  NaN    1  1
```

Comment: thanks for this answer -  I updated my question to be more specific - there are columns in my dataset that I don't want to use for constructing column 'd' (I only want to use columns 'a', 'b', and 'c'), so I think the other answer is better for my purposes. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: If you'd like to apply this to a subset, you can just index your dataframe first:  `df[['a', 'b', 'c']].apply(lambda x: x[x.first_valid_index()], axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

One more option not mentioned in the duplicated question:

```
df['d'] = df['a'].combine_first(df['b']).combine_first(df['c'])
#0    1.0
#1    1.0
#2    1.0
```