# Python 3 / Pandas | Using Function with IF & ELIF statements to populate a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Python 3 / Pandas**

I am trying to use a function to check the values of various columns in a dataframe, and select only the value from the column that is **not** NaN.

The data is structured so there is one main column `df['C1']` that I want to populate based on the value in one of the next four columns, `df['C2'], df['C3'], df['C4']` and  `df['C5']`. When I observe the data, I see that in the rows `df['C2'], df['C3'], df['C4']` and  `df['C5']`, every column has a value that is NaN except for one column which has a text value. This is true for all rows in the dataframe. I am trying to write a function that will be applied to the dataframe to find the column which has a text value, and copy that value from the column into `df['C1']`.

Here is the function I wrote:

```
def get_component(df):
    if ~df['C2'].isna():
        return df['C2']
    elif ~df['C3'].isna():
        return df['C3']
    elif ~df['C4'].isna():
        return df['C4']
    elif ~df['C5'].isna():
        return df['C5']
df['C1'] = df.apply(get_component, axis=1)
```

But I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: ("'float' object has no attribute 'isna'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

Any ideas on how to fix this error so I can achieve this objective? Is there another method to achieve the same result?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please [edit] to include samples of your input data and desired output to make a [mcve] so we can better understand your problem. See [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for more help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [First non-null value per row from a list of Pandas columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31828240/first-non-null-value-per-row-from-a-list-of-pandas-columns)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it just stumbled upon np.where and used the following code to solve the problem:

```
df['C1'] = np.where(~df['C2'].isna(),df['C2'],
                          np.where(~df['C3'].isna(),df['C3'],
                                  np.where(~df['C4'].isna(),df['C4'],
                                          np.where(~df['C5'].isna(),df['C5'],None))))
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that makes use of pandas' [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) method:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Initialize example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "C2": [np.nan, 3, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    "C3": [5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    "C4": [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 7, 3],
    "C5": [np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan],
})

df["C1"] = df.stack().to_numpy()
print(df)
# Output:
#     C2   C3   C4   C5   C1
# 0  NaN  5.0  NaN  NaN  5.0
# 1  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  3.0
# 2  NaN  NaN  NaN  2.0  2.0
# 3  NaN  NaN  7.0  NaN  7.0
# 4  NaN  NaN  3.0  NaN  3.0
```