# How to combine multiple dataframe columns into one given each column has nan values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called 'main_df' that contains 3 columns X,Y,Z.

```
X        Y       Z
NaN      NaN     ZVal1
NaN      NaN     ZVal2
XVal1    NaN     NaN
NaN      YVal1   NaN
```

Each column carries data of the specific type (X,Y,Z) so if there is data in column X for a particular row, there will be no data in columns Y/Z because it is not of type X.

If you combine all 3 columns, they "slide into each other" neatly and you will get values all the way down.

How can I combine these 3 columns into a 4th column so that NaN values are ignored and we just get whatever single value exists in the 3 columns for that row?

Expected output:

```
X        Y       Z           XYZ
NaN      NaN     ZVal1       ZVal1
NaN      NaN     ZVal2       ZVal2
XVal1    NaN     NaN         XVal1    
NaN      YVal1   NaN         YVal1
```

Dataframe code:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z'], data=[[np.NaN, np.NaN, 'ZVal1'], [np.NaN, np.NaN, 'ZVal2'], ['XVal1', np.NaN, np.NaN], [np.NaN,'YVal1' ,np.NaN]])
```

Right now I am trying to do something along the lines of:

> df['XYZ'] = df['X'].astype(str) + df['Y'].astype(str) + df['Z'].astype(str)
> but that combines the NaN values into one long string

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31828240/first-non-null-value-per-row-from-a-list-of-pandas-columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `stack`:

```
df["XYZ"] = df.stack().values
```

to get

```
>>> df

       X      Y      Z    XYZ
0    NaN    NaN  ZVal1  ZVal1
1    NaN    NaN  ZVal2  ZVal2
2  XVal1    NaN    NaN  XVal1
3    NaN  YVal1    NaN  YVal1
```

since you guarantee only 1 non-NaN per row and `stack` drops NaNs by default.

---

Another way with fancy indexing:

```
df["XYZ"] = df.to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)),
                          df.columns.get_indexer(df.notna().idxmax(axis=1))]
```

which, for each row, looks at the index of the non-NaN value and selects it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df["XYZ"] = df.apply(lambda x: x[x.notna()][0], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       X      Y      Z    XYZ
0    NaN    NaN  ZVal1  ZVal1
1    NaN    NaN  ZVal2  ZVal2
2  XVal1    NaN    NaN  XVal1
3    NaN  YVal1    NaN  YVal1
```

---

Or:

```py
df["XYZ"] = df.bfill(axis=1)["X"]
print(df)
```

Comment: Sir I already posted the second method **:)**

Comment: @AnuragDabas I think we are on the same wave :)