# get the non nan value from columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | nan | nan |
| nan | 1 | nan |
| nan | nan | nan |
| nan | nan | 1 |

And I need to collapse those columns into something like this:

| foo |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| nan |
| 1 |

My first attempt was doing this:

```
df[columns].values[~df[columns].isna()]
```

But since there are rows where all the values are nan, I miss those rows.

My second attempt was doing this:

```
def get_cols_or_nan(row):
    mask = ~row.isna()
    if np.any(mask):
        return row[mask][0]
    
    return float('nan')
    

df[columns].apply(get_cols_or_nan, axis=1)
```

But, I don't know why, this is significantly slower to the point that for me it's impracticable.

Is there a more efficient way that I can collapse those columns? I am guaranteed that there's only one non-nan value in each row.

Comment: what should happen if you also have a number in the first row for col2?

Comment: I hadn't seen the last comment, then it's covered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31828240/first-non-null-value-per-row-from-a-list-of-pandas-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have at most one non-NA value per row, you can use:

```
df.stack().droplevel(1).reindex_like(df)
```

output:

```
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    NaN
3    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the max number in rows with `df.max(axis=1)`

```py
out = df.max(axis=1).to_frame('foo')
```

```
print(out)

   foo
0  0.0
1  1.0
2  NaN
3  1.0
```