# Merge two pandas dataframes on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes and I would like to join these dataframes based on column 'Name' of df1 and multiple columns of df2.

```
df1
Name            id
ZYMAXID 9416X   6390
ZYPRED          6391


df2
label    pref_label  alt_label
ZYPRED   None        None
None     ZYMAXID 9416X  None
```

The final output should be:

```
Name            id     label    pref_label     alt_label
ZYMAXID 9416X   6390   None     ZYMAXID 9416X  None
ZYPRED          6391   ZYPRED   None           None
```

I tried below join but it is giving me error.

```
df = df1.merge(df2, left_on=df1["Name"].str.lower(), right_on=['df2["label"].str.lower()','df2["pref_label"].str.lower()''df2["alt_label"].str.lower()', indicator = True)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the first non-None value in the labels in `df2` using the method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37938780/9473764):

```py
df2['Name'] = df2.fillna(method='bfill', axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
```

You can now merge on that value:

```
res = df1.merge(df2, on='Name')
```

Output:

```
            Name    id   label     pref_label  alt_label
0  ZYMAXID 9416X  6390     NaN  ZYMAXID 9416X        NaN
1         ZYPRED  6391  ZYPRED            NaN        NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

To match you MUST have a common column (at least one) in both dataframe.

If you just want to concat (stick) the two dataframes side by side, you can:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

If you want to merge df2 on either of the three labels you must do several merges:

```
df = df1.merge(df2['label'], left_on=df1["Name"].str.lower(), right_on='df2["label"].str.lower()', how='left')
df = df.merge(df2['label'], left_on=df1["Name"].str.lower(), right_on='df2["label"].str.lower()', how='left')
df = df.merge(df2['alt_label'], left_on=df1["Name"].str.lower(), right_on='df2["alt_label"].str.lower()', how='left')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
df1.merge(df2.assign(Name = df2.replace(np.nan, '').sum(axis=1)))
```

---

In case it is false that only one of the labels is not `None`, a possible solution is:

```
(df1.merge(
    df2.assign(Name = df2.replace(np.nan, '')
               .apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates().sum(), axis=1))))
```

---

Output:

```
            Name    id   label     pref_label alt_label
0  ZYMAXID 9416X  6390    None  ZYMAXID 9416X      None
1         ZYPRED  6391  ZYPRED           None      None
```

Comment: This will only work if only one of the labels is not None.